# How to extract used byte array from ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, arrays, guava, nio, bytebuffer

The `java.nio.ByteBuffer` class has a `ByteBuffer.array()` method, however this returns an array that is the size of the buffer's capacity, and not the used capacity. Due to this, I'm having some issues.

I have a ByteBuffer which I am allocating as some size and then I am inserting data to it.

```
ByteBuffer oldBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);
addHeader(oldBuffer, pendingItems);
newBuffer.flip();
oldBuffer.put(newBuffer);
// as of now I am sending everything from oldBuffer
send(address, oldBuffer.array());
```

How can I just send what is being used in `oldBuffer`. Is there any one liner to do this?

Comment: It would be simpler to modify your `send()` method to either accept a length (and an offset) or to take the actual `ByteBuffer` as a parameter. You shouldn't be copying data around like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flip the buffer, then create a new array with the remaining size of the buffer and fill it.

```java
oldBuffer.flip();
byte[] remaining = new byte[oldBuffer.remaining()];
oldBuffer.get(remaining);
```

Another way in a one liner with `flip()` and [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(byte[],%20int))

```java
oldBuffer.flip();
Arrays.copyOf(oldBuffer.array(), oldBuffer.remaining());
```

And without `flip()`

```java
Arrays.copyOf(oldBuffer.array(), oldBuffer.position());
```

Also like EJP said, if you have access to the `send(..)` method, you can add a size and offset argument to the `send()` method, and avoid the need to create and fill a new array.

Comment: yes I do have access to `send` method so what changes we can do their? can you provide an example on that just to make myself clear?

Comment: Well that depends on how you handle the data in the `send` method, if you eventually will need the array of that length, you can do it this way and just call the `send(..)` method and without modifing anything. Also if the data is not that much you can just copy the array.

Comment: Yes I do need byte array in that send method of that length. Also what is the difference between `with flip() version` vs `without flip() version`?

Comment: Well if sooner or later you'll need the array of that length, so you can do it sooner. `Flip()` changes the limit, position and mark values of the `ByteBuffer`, is normally used before reading. The array is the same, so practically not much a difference, and if you aren't going to use that buffer anymore, there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `position()` of the buffer indicates that the amount of *used* data in the buffer.

So create a byte array of that size.

Next go to the position 0 of the buffer, since you have to read data from there. `rewind()` does this.

Then use the `get()` method to copy the buffer data into the array.

```
byte[] data = new byte[buffer.position()];
buffer.rewind();
buffer.get(data);
```

Also note that `buffer.array()` works only if the `buffer.hasArray()` returns true. So check for `hasArray()`before calling it. Otherwise, `buffer.array()` will throw any of the following exception.

1. `UnsupportedOperationException` - when calling it on direct buffer.
2. `ReadOnlyBufferException` - if the buffer is read-only.